How do a specify an argument of "const MyClass *varName[]"?
There's a func in a third party library which looks like this:
void MyFunc(const MyClass *varName[])
What is an example of what I can pass in as an argument to that function?
This doesn't work:
MyClass* b[1] = { a };
MyFunc(b)
Although intellisense says nothing, upon compilation, I get an error: "... cannot convert from 'MyClass *[1]' to 'const MyClass *[]'"

A (constant) pointer to an array of MyClass
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *name;
} MyClass;

void print_person(const MyClass *p[]) {
    printf("%i: %s", p[0]->id, p[0]->name);
}

int main() {
    MyClass p[] = {
        { 1, "Alice" }
    };

    const MyClass *p2 = p;

    print_person(&p2);

    return 0;
}


And to answer your interrogation, if you do this ;
MyClass* b[1] = { a };

I don't know what's a, but it shouldn't possible to instantiate a pointer this way. Or maybe you wanted do something like this ;
MyClass a = { 1, "Alice" };
MyClass *p[1] = { &a };


Thanks - I was missing the const keyword. const MyClass* b[1] = { a }; fixes it.
